# node js variable system

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am really new to node js and I am coming from java.
How does this return different values?

```
var os = require("os");

var osTime = "" + os.uptime;
var osTime2 = os.uptime;
```

it gives out:

```
19895

[Function: getUptime] {
  [Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive)]: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

can the console not give out integers?

Comment: The first one converts to a string implicitly. The second one is just the raw value, which seems to be an object.

Comment: Please note that this isn’t node specific, but is JavaScript converting types as the plus operator is overloaded with addition and string concatenation

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Node, but from the output there it appears that `os.uptime` is a function which overrides its string/number coercion for some very specific reason. (That's what the `Symbol.toPrimitive` stuff means, and it's observed by the output when you stringify it by adding to `""`.)

Comment: ah ok, so I basically first make it to a string and in the second line it keeps its object form

Comment: According to the docs it's supposed to be called as function: `os.uptime()`, and then you get an actual number. However it seems this function additionally has a `toPrimitive` symbol set that refers to itself so using the function (without calling it) as if it was a number (in calculations, comparisons or also in this case in a string concatenation) will implicitly call it. I'm not sure why, but for example it could be that it was a getter and not a function in the past, and for compatibility reasons they turned it into sort of a hybrid... But I don't really know

Comment: @CherryDT ohhh, that makes so much sense, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was implemented this way [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/os.js#L94)

```js
getUptime[SymbolToPrimitive] = () => getUptime();

// ...
module.exports = {
  uptime: getUptime,
}
```

While `Symbol.toPrimitive` is a symbol that specifies a function valued property that is called to convert an object to a corresponding primitive value.

An example

```js
const func1 = function() {}
func1[Symbol.toPrimitive] = () => "42";
console.log(+func1);
```

Read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive

Answer (score 0):

os.uptime is not a string primitive, but an object.

Complex javascript objects can provide a methods that are going to be automatically called when a casting is required, and in the first case it will be invoked before concatenating it to the empty string.

In that case the method implemented is a [toPrimitive Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive), but you can also provide other casting methods like [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/ValueOf), [toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)